# Liquid Exception in atom.xml

Tags: ruby, regex, liquid, octopress

I am using Octopress to write a blog.  But originally it did not support Tex, so I sought some guidance online.  In the end, I failed to use Tex&markdown.

To make the problem worse, the following problem occurs:

```
lo@lo:~/blog/octopress$ rake generate
## Generating Site with Jekyll
unchanged sass/screen.scss
unchanged sass/syntax/syntax.scss
unchanged sass/bootstrap/responsive.scss
unchanged sass/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss
Configuration from /home/lo/blog/octopress/_config.yml
Building site: source -> public
Liquid Exception: Variable '{{' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\}\}/  in    atom.xml
Liquid Exception: Variable '{{' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\}\}/  in atom.xml
Liquid Exception: Variable '{{' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\}\}/  in atom.xml
Successfully generated site: source -> public
lo@lo:~/blog/octopress$`
```

Now I have no idea how to fix it.

I tried to `diff` all the files in `/octopress` and `/octopress.bk`.
In the end, I find that i had used wrong grammars in the `*.markdown.`

I wrote `\{\{\{   \}\}\}`, which lead to the problem. 
Now I solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your atom.xml file was changed. You can find it in the root of the folder that contains your website. What you need to find is the unmatched {{ tag }}. Most likely one of the brackets is missing, like a {{ with just one } closing it.

Here is the default atom.xml file that you can use as an example:

```
---
layout: nil
---
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">

 <title>Your Title</title>
 <link href="http://www.example.com/atom.xml" rel="self"/>
 <link href="http://www.example.com/"/>
 <updated>{{ site.time | date_to_xmlschema }}</updated>
 <id>http://www.example.com/</id>
 <author>
   <name>Your Name/name>
   <email>Your Email</email>
 </author>

 {% for post in site.posts %}
 <entry>
   <title>{{ post.title }}</title>
   <link href="http://www.example.com{{ post.url }}"/>
   <updated>{{ post.date | date_to_xmlschema }}</updated>
   <id>http://www.example.com{{ post.id }}</id>
   <content type="html">{{ post.content | xml_escape }}</content>
 </entry>
 {% endfor %}

</feed>
```

Comment: I tried to `diff` all the files in `/octopress` and `/octopress.bk`.             In the end, I find that i had used wrong grammars in the *.markdown.